# How to create url to Stripe checkout page?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I use following code to create button to Stripe checkout page:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'T-shirt',
      ],
      'unit_amount' => 2000,
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
]);
?>


<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


<a href="#" id="checkout-button">BUY</a>


<script type="text/javascript">  
var stripe = Stripe('xxxx');
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: '<?=$session['id'];?>'
  }).then(function (result) {
  });
});
</script>
```

How to create direct url to Stripe checkout page, like $checkout_url = ...?

I need to use it with chatbot, where i can't use JS.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: At the moment, Checkout requires a redirection client-side with Stripe.js. You can not redirect directly from the server which is why you are not seeing a url at that point.

Comment: I just need to generate url and set it to the chatbot PAY button.

Comment: I understand, it's jut not possible at the moment